Convergence in probability results with still open point-wise versions
In ergodic theory and more generally in stochastic processes, often convergence in probability results precede convergence almost-surely results in quite a few years. Classical examples include the mean ergodic theorem preceding the point-wise ergodic theorem and Shannon-McMillan theorem preceding Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theorem.
Commenters are invited to mention results proven for convergence in probability but that are still open problems regarding to convergence almost-surely.

Let $X=(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ with $p\in(1/2,1)$, where $p$ is the probability of an upward step. Let $Y_n=I(\text{both $X_n$ and $X_n+2$ are prime})$. It's known that $Y_n\to 0$ in probability but it's not known if the a.s. convergence holds. (In comparison, for $Z_n=I(\text{$X_n$ is prime})$ then again the convergence in probability holds, but the a.s convergence is known to fail.)

Thanks. Though I am more interested in convergence in probability results that are expected to also be true for convergence almost-surely.

I was being slightly flippant (apologies). If you want an example in a similar spirit where convergence almost surely is expected, you can take $W_n$ to be the indicator function of the event that $X_n >\max(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})$ and $X_n$ is not the sum of three primes.

But this proven, no?

It would imply Goldbach's conjecture, wouldn't it? If 100 is the sum of three primes then 98 is the sum of two primes etc.
